# Compare Time Stamps in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I pull a time stamp off the database with a query, How can I compare that time stamp with the current time. I am trying to make the output say, "Updated X minutes ago".

The format of the time stamp off the server is YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS (24hr system)

Thanks!

Comment: `strtotime` should be able to handle that format

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=time+ago+php

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113940/php-compare-date

Comment: possible duplicate of [X Time Ago in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580278/x-time-ago-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

You can convert most dates (including those sourced from MySQL) with `strtotime()` into a unix timestamp (a count of the seconds since Jan 1st 1970)

So you could do

```
$then = $your_date_from_mysql;
$now = time();
$time_ago = $now - strtotime($then); //gets time ago in seconds
$minutes = $time_ago / 60; //you could call floor() on this to round it down - or ceil() to round up
echo "Updated {$minutes} minutes ago";
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using MySQL:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestampfield) AS seconds
```

and then

```
echo "Updated ", ceil($seconds / 60), " seconds ago";
```

It's better to have the database do the computing - it's already got the timestamp in an internal format that's easily amenable to these sorts of calculations. Selecting out a formatted string, then converting the string back to a time value, etc... is just a waste of computing time.

Comment: Thanks, make one edit to you second part of code, should be minutes not seconds.

Comment: That's what the `/ 60` part is - take the seconds that mysql returns and convert to minutes.